# Searching for an element inside an array

Tags: java, arrays

Im kinda lost here, this is what i got so far.

MAIN class

```
package index;

public class Index {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Array Arraylisteishon= new Array(4);
        Arraylisteishon.AgregarElemento("1-1");
        Arraylisteishon.AgregarElemento("1-2");
        Arraylisteishon.AgregarElemento("1-3");
        Arraylisteishon.AgregarElemento("1-4");
        Arraylisteishon.AgregarElemento("1-5");
        Arraylisteishon.AgregarElemento("1-6");

        Arraylisteishon.BuscarElemento("1-2");
    }
}
```

Arraylisteishon is the name of my array, agregarElemento is the name of my method and the method I need help with is BuscarElemento, which means SearchElement, it should return the position of the element, in this case "1"

Here are my methods:

```
package index;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author juane
 */
public class Array {
    public int Dimension;
    public ArrayList<String> array;
    String nombre;
    String path;
    File archivo;

    public Array (String nombre, String path) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.path = path;
        ArrayList<String> array;
    }

    //Metodos

    public Array (int Dimension) {
        this.Dimension = Dimension;
        this.array= new ArrayList<String>();

    }

    public void AgregarElemento(String elemento) {
        if (array.size()< this.Dimension) {
            this.array.add(elemento);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se agrego el elemento");
        }
    }

    public int BuscarElemento(String element) {
        int i=0;
        String linea;   
        boolean encontrado= false;                              
        while (linea()!=null) {    
            i++;
            if (linea.indexOf(element)!=-1) {               
                    System.out.println("Pos elemento= "+i);
                    encontrado=true;
                    break;
            }               
        }

        if (!encontrado) {          
            i = -1;
        }       
        return i;
    }
}
```

I need help with the SearchElement (Buscar elemento)

Comment: AgregarElemento means AddElement

Comment: Explain your "BuscarElemento" to a [Rubber Duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) - it makes no sense...

Comment: Why not directly use `array.indexOf(element)`?

Comment: and lose the `dimension` for this ArrayList look-a-like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your BuscarElemento method should be:

```
 public int BuscarElemento(String element) {
            return array.indexOf(element);
        }
```

And you have to print the return of that method

```
 System.out.println(Arraylisteishon.BuscarElemento("1-2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void BuscarElemento (String element){
        System.out.println(array.indexOf(element));
    }
```

I need to go sleep